# TransformerColumnKeyLoader not work with spring boot 3.x.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to use TransformKeyLoaderConfiguration solution with spring boot 3.0.3. But I encountered a problem at the moment of getting data from the database. The column name is not changing. I debug the program and I found that the key is changing the moment of configuring the bean but not at the moment of getting the result.

Any suggestions please?

@ColumnTransfomer: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUs6A.png)

Change of value when debugging : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRBEx.png)

Console error when getting data => the value is restested to '${encryption.key}' [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeNA5.png)

I expected that the value of ${encryption.key} change to key added in application.properties